# Support fonts set dynamically in UITextView attributed string

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, nsattributedstring

I have to support rich text in UITextView. I unable to show different parts of the the text set in different fonts types and sizes.

I already tired using document type NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html and character encoding utf8 to convert the text data to attributed string.

```swift
 if let richTextData = richText.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: false), let attributedString = try?  NSAttributedString(data: richTextData, options: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html, .characterEncoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue], documentAttributes: nil) {
            textView.attributedText = attributedString
 }
```

I am trying to process text something like this

```
“<p>Hello World :</p>\n\n<p>&nbsp;</p>\n\n<p><strong>Manager</strong> for the team. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea <em>commodo</em> consequat. <u>Duis</u> aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, <span style=\“font-size:18px;\“><span style=\“font-family:Comic Sans MS,cursive;\“>sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est </span></span><span style=\“color:#d35400\“><span style=\“font-size:20.0px\“><span style=\“font-family:Lucida Sans Unicode, Lucida Grande, sans-serif\“>laborum</span></span></span>.</p>“
```

The color and spacing are working but font size and font-family are not.

Comment: If the font is not present on the device, it won't be correctly interpreted.

Comment: I tried with simpler ones with just font size, it does not seem to work.